# Numbers being read as NaN with pandas.read_csv; how do I fix this problem?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
  import pandas as pd

    depth = []
    tipres = []
    fric = []
    pore = []
    incline = []

    data = pd.read_csv('93Z181.CPD' ,sep=' ',header=None, usecols=[1,2, 3, 4, 5],na_values = None)
    depth = data[2].values
    tipres = data[3].values
    fric = data[4].values
    pore = data[5].values
```

When I try to view my arrays, about half come back as NaN, and I'm quite new to python so I am not sure how to go about fixing this issue. Here is a sample of what the data looks like:

Column 1 for example, returns as NaN however for values ranging from 0.05 to 9.95 it returns the actual number.

```
12.90   58.85   0.568   -0.24   10.11
12.95   58.81   0.786   -0.20   10.17
13.00   52.73   0.604    2.46   10.19
13.05   48.18   0.509    0.90   10.20
13.10   38.03   0.434    1.61   10.21
13.15   29.96   0.269    1.97   10.23
13.20   26.22   0.275    2.30   10.26
13.25   20.65   0.715    2.97   10.27
13.30   69.26   0.716    3.56   10.35
13.35  184.57   0.721    0.37   10.40
13.40  265.01   0.851   -1.18   10.43
13.45  268.07   1.032   -2.10   10.48
```

Comment: Well, what do you think the values should come back as, instead? What is the corresponding data in your CSV file? Does it make sense to interpret that data as a floating-point number?

Comment: I expect the values to come back as the first column in the provided sample data. Another thing I maybe should have added is that it's a .CPD file

Comment: I've never heard of .CPD. Did you try viewing the file in a text editor? Do you understand what it *should* look like in a text editor? How about a spreadsheet program - is it able to open the file and make sense of it?

Comment: Can you produce a small example of an input file that other people could test with and see the same problem you do?